# Css arrow under menu item

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Good day everyone!
I got a simple menu,and i am trying to make a hover arrow for each item
the way it should look:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFTfM.png). I have got this code already
thanks for any advice!

```css
.mainmenu{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.mainmenu_item{
 display: inline;
 padding-right:8px;
}
.mainmenu_link{
 font-family:FrutigerCELight,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size:14px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Services">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can achieve this with css pseudo elements (**:after**, **:before**)

Comment: i know,that's why i added pseudo-elements category tag for this question lmao,i need some example, so i can analyze it.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/ google it bro!

Comment: do you really think i haven't been there already?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add pseudo element on hover first you need to target :hover and then add pseudo element. Your selector will be .mainmenu_item:hover:after

```css
.mainmenu{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-left: 0px;
    font-size:0;
}
.mainmenu_item{
    font-size: 14px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:8px;
    position: relative;
    line-height:2em;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.mainmenu_item a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: currentColor;
}
.mainmenu_item:hover:after {
    content:'';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid currentColor;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.mainmenu_link{
 font-family:FrutigerCELight,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Services">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainmenu_item"><a class="mainmenu_link" href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<span class="arrow-up"></span>` after every `a` tag.

then add css:

```
.mainmenu_item:hover .arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top:33px;
  left:40%;
}
```

Try it your self https://jsfiddle.net/5fbuLh7g/